# ¿Por qué no se sube bien mis archivos a github?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit

Buenas he tratado de subir un proyecto de eclipse a github pero cuando lo quiero subir en mi consola sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

```
c:\> cd ruta de mi archivo

c:\ruta de mi archivo> git init

c:\ruta de mi archivo>git add .

c:\ruta de mi archivo>git commit -m "nuevos cambios"

c:\ruta de mi archivo>git remote add origin ruta del repositorio remoto

c:\ruta de mi archivo>git push -u origin master
```

y luego me sale ese mensaje en la consola , despues puse git pull y supuestamente se subio el commit que le mande , pero no aparece sino que dice algo en ingles como : initial commit  y el archivo que supuestamente subi no aparece, solo ese commit.
Le puse git pull por que en la consola decia que haga eso antes de poner git push pero esta todo igual.

Comment: ya intentaste primero hacer un `git pull` y después tu `git push -u origin master`?

Comment: ahi lo hice y me aparece lo mismo

Comment: bueno al final borre ese repositorio y cree otro(y pude subir mi archivo en el nuevo repositorio remoto :D) , porque cuando hice este di click en : Initialize this repository with a READM , y creo que eso es lo que no me estaba dejando subir de forma correcta mi proyecto .

Comment: Toma, esto es justo y necesario: https://www.katacoda.com/courses/git/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como mencionas en tu comentario:

> "... di click en : 'Initialize this repository with a README'.."

Al hacer esto cuando creas tu repositorio remoto, estás generando un primer commit al añadir el archivo `README`. En este punto, lo que debes hacer es **clonar** el repositorio remoto ya que existe contenido en el.

Cuando hiciste `git init` y `git commit`, creaste un repositorio local y añadiste contenido **al repositorio local**. En este punto los dos repositorios no tienen niguna relación el uno con el otro, y sus historias de commits son diferentes

Ahora, cuando añades el repo de github como remoto del local, e intentas hacer push, estás intentando que el repo local sobreescriba lo que hay en github, lo cual no es permitido.

Cuando haces `git pull` lo que buscas es que tu **repositorio local** se actualice con lo que está en el **repositorio remoto**.